# Add a temporarily link in plesk

Tags: plesk

I normaly use cPanel, but im using Plesk right now. And I can't find a way to use a temporarily link to a domain I have made in Plesk.

Does anyone know if it is possible to get a temporarily link in Plesk ?

Comment: Do you mean URL for preview domain which can't be resolved right now?

Answer (score 0):

cPanel's term "Temporary URL" is a "Preview" in Plesk:

[image: plesk domain temporary URL / preview URL]